# Update column of soft-deleted record (paranoia)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to update column of soft-deleted record on Ruby on Rails.
The code is

```
item = Item.with_deleted.find_by(name: name)
item.title = "foo"
item.save!
```

For not soft-deleted record, this works fine,
but for soft-deleted record, this error is outputted on " item.save! ".

> Couldn't find Item with 'id'=4 [WHERE `items`.`deleted_at` IS NULL]

This code has same result.

```
item = Item.with_deleted.find_by(name: name).update!(title: 'foo')
```

Seem oddly, in "rails console", these code works fine.
In "rails server", they doesn't work.

Any information would greatly help.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Item.with_deleted.find_by(name: name).with_deleted.update!(title: 'foo')` ? It might be that the item once found using `with_deleted` no longer carries the finder scope when calling .update. I don't know if that helps, but if it doesn't, you might be happy to use something like `Item.update_all(["name=?", name], title: 'foo').limit(1)` which will however bypass all validation and callback logic of your model.